# Java dialog with text and button

Tags: java, swing, input, dialog

How do I make a dialog that has a text at the top and under it a blank space where the user can type and under it on the right an <kbd>OKAY</kbd> button where when you click on it the dialog disappears?

Like this:

[image: Input dialog]

Answer (score 4):

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..);
```

For more information see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).  Here is an example from that document.

```
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                this,
                "Complete the sentence:\n"
                + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                "Customized Dialog",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                null,
                "ham");
```

[image: JOptionPane requesting input]

Comment: can you explain to me more ?

Comment: I'm not expecting that, ty for the link

Comment: can I make it with ok only ? not ok and cancel ?

Comment: `can I make it with ok only ` Did you read the tutorial??? I find it hard to believe you read the entire tutorial in 11 minutes and then tried experimenting with some of the concepts found in the tutorial.